# Show one paragraph Right-to-Left and another Left-to-Right in Notepad

Tags: notepad, right-to-left

I have 2 paragraphs in Notepad. I want one paragraph to be displayed from Left-to-Right, and the other from Right-to-Left. How do I do that?

Comment: You can't in Notepad.

Comment: That is not possible in notepad.It is default on right to left format.